# After install djanog and try to runserver manage.py I get ImportError

Tags: django

I'm new and trying to follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc

from 05:00:00 I follow him just like he doing, then at 05:05:04 when he run the server it's work fine for him, but for me is not.

This is exactly my steps....

After Install django like this:

```
pip install django
```

I write this:

```
django-admin startproject pyshop .
```

so far all good, no error, then I try to run the server like this:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But then I get a big error:

```
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001D36DA79AF0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 304, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "D:\User\OneDrive\Programing Code\Python\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.
```

Help :(

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing this error, but maybe try python3 manage.py runserver if you have multiple versions installed.

Comment: Are you in the correct directory? Your terminal has the be inside the folder where the manage.py file is.

Answer (score 0):

Try by downloading the [sqlite3 dll](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)  (find version that supports your system)

And put it into the folder: C:\Users\YOURUSER\Anaconda3\DLLs

Answer (score 0):

Install [python3](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.1/python-3.9.1-amd64.exe) and then run python3 manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're not using Anaconda, you can download [sqlite3 dll](https://sqlite.org/download.html) and add it to your system32 C:\Windows\System32 if you're using windows that is